# How to convert angular-moment time to date format like Thu Jan 01 1970 15:00:00 GMT+0000 (Country)

Tags: angularjs, angular, date, angularjs-directive, angular-moment

I am using angular-moment-picker to set time ( hours and minutes). Whenever i want to to save data I got time like `HH:mm`. My aimis to convert this time to date  format since 1970 as follows:  `Thu Jan 01 1970 15:00:00 GMT+0000 (Country)`
where the 15:00 is time setted in angular-moment-picker
here is my source code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <p class="icon-group input-group ">
    <input readonly ng-model="workTime.startTime" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-btn ">
      <button moment-picker="workTime.startTime" format="HH:mm" type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="startTime">
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
      </button>
    </span>
    <span class="show-date-picker"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your angular controller you can instantiate the Date:

```
var startDate=new Date();
```

Then you can set the Day, Month, and the Year for this date as suggested.
After that you split and set the time to your date as follow:

```
var start=$scope.startTime.toString().trim().split(':');
startDate.setHours(start[0]);
startDate.setMinutes(start[1]);
startDate.setSeconds(0);
```

It works for me.

Best Regards